# Connect-MicrosoftTeams OAuth Invalid audiences error

Tags: powershell, oauth, microsoft-teams

I'm using the Connect-MicrosoftTeam cmdlet with OAuth access tokens but I get an error about invalid audiences. I'm using v2.3.2 of the MicrosoftTeams PowerShell module with the new `-AccessTokens` parameter, there is not much help available so I am probably doing something wrong.

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccessTokens @($graph_tokenResponse.access_token, $teams_tokenResponse.access_token) -AccountId $accountId
Connect-MicrosoftTeams : Invalid audiences 48ac35b8-9aa8-4d74-927d-1f4a14a0b239 found in the provided tokens
```

This is the script that I am using to test this it:

```
$graph_tokenBody = @{  
   Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"  
   Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"  
   Client_Id     = $clientId  
   Client_Secret = $clientSecret  
}   
$graph_tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $graph_tokenBody  

$teams_tokenBody = @{  
   Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"  
   Scope         = "https://api.interfaces.records.teams.microsoft.com/.default"  
   Client_Id     = $clientId  
   Client_Secret = $clientSecret  
}   
$teams_tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $teams_tokenBody  

Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccessTokens @($graph_tokenResponse.access_token, $teams_tokenResponse.access_token) -AccountId $accountId
```

The id in the error message `48ac35b8-9aa8-4d74-927d-1f4a14a0b239` is the application ID of the "Skype and Teams Tenant Admin API" application, I worked out the scope from that.

Is there still a bug in the MicrosofTeams module or am I using the wrong scope or something?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have updated the documentation for `Connect-MicrosftTeams`, it now includes the following in the [AccessTokens example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/connect-microsoftteams?view=teams-ps#example-4--connect-to-microsoftteams-using-accesstokens):

```
$graphtoken = #Get MSGraph Token for following for resource  "https://graph.microsoft.com" and scopes "AppCatalog.ReadWrite.All", "Group.ReadWrite.All", "User.Read.All";
$teamstoken = #Get Teams resource token for resource id "48ac35b8-9aa8-4d74-927d-1f4a14a0b239" and scope "user_impersonation";
```

I've updated my app and now `Connect-MicrosftTeams` works.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for submitting this as an answer (not enough reputation and this isn't likely to help) but can you please state how you updated your app? The documentation is unclear on how to go about obtaining a token for "resource id" and "scope" as mentioned.

Comment: Scopes should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` for the graph token and `48ac35b8-9aa8-4d74-927d-1f4a14a0b239/.default` for the teams token

Comment: Of course it would be that simple... the one thing I didn't try for some reason. This works; but set-csuser afterwards fails with ```Get-CsOnlineSession : Connecting to remote server api.interfaces.records.teams.microsoft.com failed with the following
error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. The authentication mechanism requested by the client is
not supported by the server or unencrypted traffic is disabled in the service configuration.``` which is no different than certificate authentication and therefore unhelpful. Must be something in the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the permisions necesary in app this code works:

```
$ClientID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$ClientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$ClientSecret = [Net.WebUtility]::URLEncode($ClientSecret)
$TenantID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$Username="example@yourdomain.com"

$URI = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$Body = "client_id=$ClientID&client_secret=$ClientSecret&grant_type=client_credentials"
$RequestParameters = @{
  URI = $URI
  Method = "POST"
  ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
$GraphToken = (Invoke-RestMethod @RequestParameters -Body "$Body&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default").access_token
$TeamsToken = (Invoke-RestMethod @RequestParameters -Body "$Body&scope=48ac35b8-9aa8-4d74-927d-1f4a14a0b239/.default").access_token
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccessTokens @($GraphToken, $TeamsToken) -Tenantid $TenantID -AccountId $Username
```